# Producing 3D video for Apple’s Vision Pro headset

Tags: 3d, apple

What format will 3D video on Apple’s new Vision Pro headset take? What are the recommended specs and processes for creating 3D video for the headset?

Comment: Sign up for the devkit in July & you'll have all the info you need - https://developer.apple.com/visionos/